# List of data- attribute to pass values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I've got a list of data attribute, however, the jquery only gets the first list value, when click second or third "test", the alert only shows "house". http://jsfiddle.net/ar1bd4bj/2/

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
<a  data-loc="house" href="#">test</a>        
    </li>
<li>
<a  data-loc="house-2" href="#">test</a>
</li>
    <li>
<a  data-loc="house-3" href="#">test</a>
</li>
</ul>

<script>

$( "ul.list li > a" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $('ul.list li > a').data('loc');
     window.location.hash = (data);
    alert(data);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` instead of selector:

```
var data = $(this).data('loc');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar1bd4bj/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` to refer to the current clicked `element`

```
$( "ul.list li > a" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).data('loc'); //here
    window.location.hash = (data);
    alert(data);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ar1bd4bj/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

your current code always picks first matching element and showing the result, I have modified the code to pick the data from element clicked.

```
$( "ul.list li > a" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = $(e.target).attr('data-loc');
         window.location.hash = (data);
        alert(data);

    });
```